# Is there an OS X dashboard widget for notes from the iPhone Notes app? 

Tags: software-recommendation, dashboard-widget, notes.app

I'm looking for a Dashboard widget for OS X that allows you to read and edit *notes*—the pieces of text in **iPhone Notes application** and **Mail.app**. (I.e., something analogous to the [To Do Widget](http://todo.philipefatio.com/) which shows the same To Do items that you can access through iCal.)

I don't use Mail.app regularly and would like some quicker way to access the notes synced from my iPhone.

Edit: To reiterate, this question is **specifically** about the notes in [iPhone's Notes app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OEWl.png) (screenshot below) and in Mail.app. (And not e.g. about alternative notes apps for iPhone/OS X or iCal's To Do items.)

[image]

Comment: I asked about this ~year ago at [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=725091) but have so far only got lots of "me, too!" answers and a couple of misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer my original question either (which is about an *OS X dashboard widget* for accessing Notes), but it is the most useful note syncing solution I've found so far:

**You can now (with iOS 4) sync Notes over the air with any IMAP email account**. And MobileMe accounts too, as the relevant Apple support article points out: [iPhone and iPod touch: Syncing Notes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4191).

Specifically, you can easily sync Notes with your **Gmail** account. [This blog post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/06/save-iphone-notes-to-gmail-account.html) gives good instructions with screenshots.

[image]

Of course, in a way, a cloud-based approach like this is even better than having a widget on the *one* Mac you sync your iPhone with. There's this drawback though:

> The notes can only be edited from an
>   iPhone or iPod Touch

In other words, you can only *view* them in Gmail.

Comment: You have already been very patient, so wait a few more months for Mountain Lion, and enjoy a genuine Notes Mac OS X App that syncs over iCloud and is editable from any location :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a way to sync and edit notes, then I suggest [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/). It isn't a Dashboard widget, but it's very lightweight and all of your notes are saved to a central server that all of your devices can see.

Comment: Not really an answer to the specific question I had, but thanks anyway, maybe I'll try it out sometime.

Comment: +1 on simplenote, this replaced using the built in notes for me. There is also a dashboard widget, and a great app called Notational Velocity will sync to give you even more power.

Comment: I agree. If you don't use the Mail application anyway, why bother using the built-in note app on the iPhone? A combination of Simplenote and its dashboard widget or Notational Velocity will do exactly what you want, and give you more flexibility and power.

Comment: I agree on Simplenote and you can couple it with nvALT or Notational Velocity for a nice combination. That said, I've heard Mountain Lion will have this capability built in: the Notes app in iOS will sync with a notes app on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR [Organized](http://islayer.com/apps/organized/) does what you want (among other things).

Comment: This looked promising; I downloaded it & tried it, but unfortunately it does not sync notes with Mail.app or iPhone Notes.   :/ There are notes yes (and the UI even looks like the iPhone Notes app), but they are not synced with anything.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It does sync To Dos and uses iCal etc., but it doesn't sync notes. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck with the same question but what I've managed to find is a useful widget for the mail.app and ical todo's. You can download it at http://todo.philipefatio.com/

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you'll notice I already mention that widget in the first paragraph. As you say, it's about To-do's, **not** Notes.